# KnockoutJS nested foreach not defined

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'll keep it short. My view model looks like this:

```
var ViewModel = {
    Cameras: ko.observableArray(),
    Current: ko.observableArray()
};
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Cameras -->
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 data-bind="text: CameraName"></h3>
        <!-- ko foreach: Current -->
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: URL }" />
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

CameraName property is from Cameras array and URL property is from Current array, but when I do this I get "Current is not defined". I've looked into nested foreach but there must be something I'm not understanding properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Current` has to be a property of the item in `Cameras`.

Like so...

```
var Camera = function() {
    this.Current = ...
}
```

You could try Knockout 2.1's `$parent`.

```
<!-- ko foreach: Cameras -->
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 data-bind="text: CameraName"></h3>
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.Current -->
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: URL }" />
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Cameras array is populated at document ready but Current array is repopulated at different times. It might even be empty when Knockout loops through Cameras. Is there no way to do this with two different arrays (like in my question above)?

Comment: $parent was the key:) Thank you very much my friend!

Comment: @ViktorBlöndal not a problem. :)